# How can i close this navbar when user clicks a link on mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The navbar is not closing when a user clicks on links to navigate through website?

I had tried to add a click event listener to every link to close navbar but it didn't work!
Also the hamberberger menu icon in active position i.e. X is not aligned well. But the major preblem is to collapse the navbar when clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').click(function() {
    $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
  });
});
function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 1104px) {
.about .about-content .left img {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
.max-width {
    padding: 0 50px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 947px) {
.menu-btn {
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
}
/* .menu-btn i.active:before {
    content: "\f00d";
} */
.navbar .menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    background: #111;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.navbar .menu.active {
    left: 0;
}
.navbar .menu li {
    display: block;
}
.navbar .menu li a {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 25px;
}
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: crimson;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 3px 1px 8px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar .logo a::after {
  content: 'PANDEY';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  bottom: -12px;
  /* color: crimson; */
  right: 15px;
  background: crimson;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* box-shadow: inset 3px 1px 8px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%); */
  padding: 0px 4px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar .logo a span {
  color: crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a::after {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  color: crimson;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bar1 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.bar2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.bar3 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  transform: translate(0, -6px) rotate(40deg);
  width: 35px;
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar.sticky .menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1  /jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="max-width">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#">Chhailbihari</a></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-btn"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-btn"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-btn"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="menu-btn"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li class="menu-btn"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you have make menu which is responsive - i.e.  works on mobile also.

1. for this use @media screen css
2. show hamburger icon when width of window is like tab or mobile else hide this icon.
3. in menu div (mobile or tab) add close icon to close menu.

hope this solution helps

you may refer below code for navbar for mobile view with hamburger icon.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #cdcdcd;
 
}
#togglmenu
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#togglmenu a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
#togglmenu a:hover
{
  color: tomato;
}
#togglmenu input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#togglmenu span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}
#togglmenu span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
#togglmenu span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#togglmenu input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}
#togglmenu input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#togglmenu input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}
#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
#togglmenu input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="togglmenu">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: These notes may well point the user in a useful direction, but this does not answer the question in any detailed or actionable way. Can you provide some concrete, specific code changes that would fix the problem in the question, and clarify how those specific changes work?

Comment: Mr Mayur your answer does not fullfill the question requirements! I asked something and you answered something.

Comment: do you need hamburger navigation menu for mobile view with close function , is it correct? OR edit your question and explain in simple

Comment: Mr Mayur i wrote in a very simple way that when the menubox is in open state and user clicks on links (like contact us), the menubox should close after clicking the link.

Comment: in your question mention hamburger menu  & you want to close submenu box .  for this use display:none when click on other menus option (those option have not any subemenu).